# How to ignore attributes while serializing a class by ObjectMapper

Tags: json, jackson, spring-mvc-test, objectmapper

I have a class with lots of attributes which are required for server side logic, but a few of those are required for UI. Now when I am creating a json from the class, all the  attributes are written to json. I want to ignore some values only when it is converted to json. I Tried with `@JsonIgnore`. But it is not working.

**My Class Is**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    protected Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    protected String name;

    /**
     * This field I want to ignore in json.
     * Thus used @JsonIgnore in its getter
     */
    @JsonProperty("securityCode")
    protected String securityCode;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSecurityCode() {
        return securityCode;
    }

    public void setSecurityCode(String securityCode) {
        this.securityCode = securityCode;
    }
}
```

And I am writing this using

```
public static StringBuilder convertToJson(Object value){
        StringBuilder stringValue = new StringBuilder();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            stringValue.append(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("Error while converting to json>>",e);
        }
        return stringValue;
    }

My Expected json should contain only :

id:1
name:abc

but what I am getting is
id:1
name:abc
securityCode:_gshb_90880..some_value.
```

What is wrong here, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@JsonProperty` annotation overrides `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Remove `@JsonProperty` from `securityCode` and your desired json output will be produced.

If you want more advanced ignoring / filtering please take a look at:

`@JsonView` : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

`@JsonFilter` : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter